# How to vectorize this peak finding for loop in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, vectorization

Basically I'm writing a peak finding function that needs to be able to beat `scipy.argrelextrema` in benchmarking. Here is a link to the data I'm using, and the code:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1U-_xQRWPoyUXhQUhFgnM3ByGw-1VImKB

If this link expires, the data can be found at dukascopy bank's online historical data downloader.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('EUR_USD.csv')
data.columns = ['Date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close','volume']

data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

data = data.set_index(data.Date)

data = data[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close']]

data = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

price = data.close.values

def fft_detect(price, p=0.4):

    trans = np.fft.rfft(price)
    trans[round(p*len(trans)):] = 0
    inv = np.fft.irfft(trans)
    dy = np.gradient(inv)
    peaks_idx = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(dy)) == -2)[0] + 1
    valleys_idx = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(dy)) == 2)[0] + 1

    patt_idx = list(peaks_idx) + list(valleys_idx)
    patt_idx.sort()

    label = [x for x in np.diff(np.sign(dy)) if x != 0]

    # Look for Better Peaks

    l = 2

    new_inds = []

    for i in range(0,len(patt_idx[:-1])):

        search = np.arange(patt_idx[i]-(l+1),patt_idx[i]+(l+1))

        if label[i] == -2:
            idx = price[search].argmax()
        elif label[i] == 2:
            idx = price[search].argmin()

        new_max = search[idx]
        new_inds.append(new_max)

    plt.plot(price)
    plt.plot(inv)
    plt.scatter(patt_idx,price[patt_idx])
    plt.scatter(new_inds,price[new_inds],c='g')
    plt.show()

    return peaks_idx, price[peaks_idx]
```

It basically smoothes data using a fast fourier transform (FFT) then takes the derivative to find the minimum and maximum indices of the smoothed data, then finds the corresponding peaks on the unsmoothed data. Sometimes the peaks it finds are not idea due to some smoothing effects, so I run this for loop to search for higher or lower points for each index between the bounds specified by `l`. I need help vectorizing this `for` loop! I have no idea how to do it. Without the `for` loop, my code is about 50% faster than `scipy.argrelextrema`, but the for loop slows it down. So if I can find a way to vectorize it, it'd be a very quick, and very effective alternative to `scipy.argrelextrema`. These two images represent the data without and with the `for` loop respectively.

[image: Before the 'for' loop was added, peaks are not ideal]
[image: With the 'for' loop, peaks are much better]

Comment: Hi, how about posting some data? Its easier to try out stuff that way.

Comment: @mortysporty added data import and link in my edit.

Comment: Great :) I doubt I can solve it but I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative... it uses list comprehension which is generally faster than for-loops

```
l = 2

# Define the bounds beforehand, its marginally faster than doing it in the loop
upper = np.array(patt_idx) + l + 1
lower = np.array(patt_idx) - l - 1

# List comprehension...
new_inds = [price[low:hi].argmax() + low if lab == -2 else 
            price[low:hi].argmin() + low 
            for low, hi, lab in zip(lower, upper, label)]

# Find maximum within each interval
new_max = price[new_inds]
new_global_max = np.max(new_max)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've benchmarked your method, it is about 30% faster than mine. Results: `Second Method:  0.00032 28.42 % Speedup`

Answer (score 3):

This may do it. It's not perfect but hopefully it obtains what you want and shows you a bit how to vectorize. Happy to hear any improvements you think up

```
label = np.array(label[:-1]) # not sure why this is 1 unit longer than search.shape[0]? 

# the idea is to make the index matrix you're for looping over row by row all in one go. 
# This part is sloppy and you can improve this generation. 

search = np.vstack((np.arange(patt_idx[i]-(l+1),patt_idx[i]+(l+1)) for i in range(0,len(patt_idx[:-1])))) # you can refine this. 

# then you can make the price matrix

price = price[search]

# and you can swap the sign of elements so you only need to do argmin instead of both argmin and argmax 

price[label==-2] = - price[label==-2]

# now find the indices of the minimum price on each row 

idx = np.argmin(price,axis=1)

# and then extract the refined indices from the search matrix 

new_inds = search[np.arange(idx.shape[0]),idx] # this too can be cleaner. 
# not sure what's going on here so that search[:,idx] doesn't work for me
# probably just a misunderstanding
```

I find that this reproduces your result but I did not time it. I suspect the search generation is quite slow but probably still faster than your for loop.

Edit:

Here's a better way to produce `search`:

```
patt_idx = np.array(patt_idx)
starts = patt_idx[:-1]-(l+1)
stops = patt_idx[:-1]+(l+1)
ds = stops-starts
s0 = stops.shape[0]
s1 = ds[0]
search = np.reshape(np.repeat(stops - ds.cumsum(), ds) + np.arange(ds.sum()),(s0,s1))
```

Comment: Thank you! I've benchmarked your method: `First Method:  0.0004394054412841797 2.49 % Speedup`

Comment: you could probably vectorize a function that evaluates argmin or argmax on each row depending on whether label is positive or negative. It'd be faster than flipping the sign of many rows. If you do this I'd be curious to see it

Comment: I will try some things out and profile this method, I think that you're right about the sign flipping. May be able to use list comprehension like in the other answer. If we can get faster that 30% on this method I will accept as an answer